# AJAX and SEO friendly URL's

Tags: ajax, seo, friendly-url

Note beforehand, I've already read this: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=en-US

My pages are available via friendly URL's, e.g. http://www.wonderweddings.com/weddingshop/wedding-cameras

However, as you can see now, when using the filters on the left hand side (e.g. the "Price filters"), it is actually a regular hyperlink and the entire page is refreshed.
So now I'm considering implementing AJAX functionality. 
My thought now is to refresh the product overview using jQuery and then update the URL in the browser address bar via javascript.

So, I believe I will not be having the AJAX URLs that are mentioned in the Google reference document, but just my regular URL format as I have it today.

What I plan to do is to keep the filters as links as they are now, but instead of following the link, override the click event and use that as input to my AJAX function to refresh the products and not the entire page.
The thought is in this way Google will still be seeing my current pages with the current friendly urls because the filters are still links.

This way I hope to at least maintain my SEO rankings.

Are there any flaws in my plan? Suggestions? Comments? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your pages don't seem to depend on the fragment part of the URL (i.e. the part after the #), so the key question is this:

When someone types in one of your page's URLs does the HTML you return

1. Already contain all of the content you want Google to crawl or ...
2. Require some Javascript to run before all of your content is present.

If (1) then you don't need to worry or do anything special. If (2) then Google wont see all of your content and the Crawlable AJAX specification you mention is the solution.

Google Webmaster tools has a free "Fetch as Google" tool you can use to see how Google views you page.

Reading up about pushState() based navigation might also help here.

I work for AjaxSnapshots, a company that provides an implementation of the Crawlable AJAX specification as a service. These issues are discussed more on our site: https://ajaxsnapshots.com